# Bizarre missing resource for Apigee deploy, possible Maven issue on Windows?

Tags: git, maven, apigee

So I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.apigee.build-tools.enterprise4g:apigee-edge-maven-plugin:1.0.1:deploy (default-cli) on project reporting: MojoExecutionException: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request
[ERROR] {
[ERROR] "code" : "messaging.config.beans.InvalidResourceURLRef",
[ERROR] "message" : "Invalid resource url ref jsc://js_validateReportingWriteScope3.js in policy js_validateReportingWriteScope3 in cambiahealth-nonprod",
[ERROR] "contexts" : [ ],
[ERROR] "cause" : {
[ERROR] "code" : "messaging.config.beans.ResourceDoesNotExist",
[ERROR] "message" : "Resource with name js_validateReportingWriteScope3.js and type jsc does not exist",
```

The file definitely exists. I've tried:

1. mvn clean
2. mvn dependency:purge-local-repository
3. IntelliJ invalidate caches and restart
4. Deleting all the local files and cloning from the remote repo
5. I tried renaming the file to a new name, in hopes it would pick up the new filename (hence why you see "3" in the filenames)

My coworkers can do the deploy, but they are on Macs. I'm on Windows.

The command that fails is:

```
mvn apigee-enterprise:deploy -P$environment -Dusername=$username -Dpassword=$password
```

The command that works (but we don't want to use, because it wipes the current deploy and replaces it, losing historical info):

```
mvn apigee-enterprise:deploy -P$environment -Dapigee.options=clean -Dusername=$username -Dpassword=$password
```

What should I try? This error makes no sense to me. The .js file definitely exists.

Comment: Are you executing the command in a git bash? Because `$environment` wouldn't work in a Windows CMD session `-P%environnment%` would.

Comment: It is in Git Bash, yes! I will try that when I'm at work on Monday. Thank you.

Comment: `$environment` is the right syntax in git bash, but check is those variables are set.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy at work on Windows? (a bit like https://community.apigee.com/questions/23892/getting-error-while-trying-multiple-proxy-deployme.html or https://community.apigee.com/questions/23892/getting-error-while-trying-multiple-proxy-deployme.html)

Comment: There is definitely some kind of filter/proxy/VPN that I have to go through on my work laptop. Hmm, I'll try switching to different WiFi networks to see if that helps too. And it seems this "-f" command was helpful for that person?

Comment: Strange indeed, let us know what your tests will reveal.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I forgot to add that the command is wrapped by a .sh script we use. So those variables are definitely populated. The deploy wouldn't even attempt to kick off if they weren't (it needs the environment, username, etc.)

Comment: I suspect it is the java lib used by maven to zip the archive. To test if the zip is the real problem go to your target directory of the local working folder. It is created by maven. You should find the zipped artifact that is deployed to apigee by the script. Try to unzip, inspect if all is well, and then re-zip it. Try deploying this manually zipped version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting this XML block below in the parent POM solves the immediate issue; however, note that it has created a side effect for me: it is breaking our inclusion of additional Apigee policies that come from a parent POM and a "common" proxy that's outside the current one. As such, this is only a partial solution. My ultimate solution will be to convert over to a Mac, because this issue is only happening on Windows computers.

```
<!-- copy the full apiproxy folder to target folder -->
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                 <!--this is important -->
                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                 <!--target -->
                <outputDirectory>${target.root.dir}/apiproxy</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                         <!--source -->
                        <directory>${project.root.dir}/apiproxy</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```